# XGBoost - get probabilities after multi:softmax function

Tags: python, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I have a question regarding xgboost and multiclass. I am not using the sklearn wrapper as I always struggle with some parameters. I was wondering if it is possible to get the probability vector plus the softmax output. The following is my code:

```
param = {}
param['objective'] = 'multi:softmax'
param['booster'] = 'gbtree'
param['eta'] = 0.1
param['max_depth'] = 30
param['silent'] = 1
param['nthread'] = 4
param['num_round'] = 40
param['num_class'] = len(np.unique(label)) + 1   
model = xgb.train(param, dtrain)                                    
# predict                                                                                   
pred = model.predict(dtest)
```

I would like to be able to call a function like `predict_proba`, but I do not know if it is possible. A lot of answers (ex:https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14527/xgboost-predict-probabilities) suggest to move to the sklearn wrapper, however, I would like to stay with the normal train method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `param['objective'] = 'multi:softprob'` instead of `param['objective'] = 'multi:softmax'`, the result of the classifier is a of probabilities for each class.

See the documentation here:
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters

Comment: it's 'multi:softprob'